# Point XCode4 to my client certificate

Tags: svn, xcode4

I'm having the same problem with XCode4. My svn cmd line is set to use client certificates. Everytime I launch XCode I get a dialog saying server.mycompany.com requires a client certificate but I have no idea where to tell it to find my client .p12 and my CA pem files. I have it set correctly in ~/.subversion/servers but XCode doesn't seem to care about these configs. I'm almost certain there's a magic overriding svn config sitting somewhere that XCode relies on but I don't know where! Help?